DateFormat isn't set to mvcProperties.setDateFormat() on application start
For no reason, or because of lacking resourses the Spring boot application started failing with the below error
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1212) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:340) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:598) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:505) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:494) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]

....

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcConversionService(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:506) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d46611b.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$9(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d46611b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ca68107d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d46611b.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted

This line is a bean:
    @Bean
    @Override
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        WebConversionService conversionService = new WebConversionService(
    506:            this.mvcProperties.getDateFormat());
        addFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }

What actually happens? Is it a case when the Spring Boot app can't get system date format from locale for some resource lacking resason?

You are using an ancient version of Spring Boot at least upgrade to the newest 2.1.x version (which still isn't supported) or even better to the 2.7.x.

@M.Deinum but what was the root reason?

No idea, not without seeing what your application / configuration is doing. Generally it is a user error by trying to outsmart Spring Boot and its auto-configuration.,

@M.Deinum it was just something time-being, that has disappeared later, when there was not resourse lacking in the k8s pod. Nothing was changed in the code in order to fix that.
